# APEX Trigger to Populate Default Text in a Standard Field on Opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

I'm attempting to create 'default text' in a standard field on the Opportunity object. Obviously, I can't use system defaults since it's a standard field. I also can't use Workflows because it updates after the record is saved. I'm attempting to do it through an APEX trigger. I have the below:

```
trigger Opportunity_Defaults on Opportunity (before insert) {
for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New) {
    o.Name = 'text goes here';
}
```

}

Despite using 'before insert', this does not default until AFTER the Opportunity record is saved. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harley,

The trigger process is only kicked off when a record is saved.
I would recommend taking a look at this article [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

When a trigger is written in the way you have described, Salesforce will set the default value before the record is committed to the database.

Are you attempting to set a default value when the a user is inserting a record in the user interface?

[image]

If so, that is not supported with standard Salesforce page layouts. A custom Lightning component would be necessary to achieve that functionality.

Also, I recommend you checkout [this trail on trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/success-cloud-coding-conventions/implement-frameworks-sc) to learn about a better way to write triggers and their handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Harley, if you are on classic, you can use the URL hack to prefill the data. If you are on lightning, you would need a custom lightning component.

Comment: I'm in Lightning, so I'll need to go the component route.